# Wordpress blog posts showing up in facebook

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I have a self hosted WordPress site (not WordPress.com) which is auto posting to Facebook. I do not have any like buttons or plugins hooked up to the facebook page. The post that shows up on facebook includes the title of my post plus an image from a random post in another category. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it is on the Wordpress side, it has got to be a plugin, or in your theme files -- most likely functions.php. Are you using one of the Open Graph plugins for login? Facebook also uses Open Graph. Is the email you've set up in your Wordpress account the same as your main Facebook email?

On the Facebook side, have you previously set up a website RSS feed? Look in your Facebook profile, under Applications. Look for an RSS application (RSS Graffiti is a popular one), and deauthorize it from posting on your profile.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a plugin then there is two chances for this operation

1. An action is running in functions.php which posts the post to facebook

Check your functions.php for any facebook posting action.

1. An RSS feed which is already setup with facebook.

Go Facebook profile > Applications > RSS

Comment: I think there's an echo in here! :-D

Comment: I found the issue - a twitterfeed account. thanks to all for your suggestions.

Comment: It is not an echo. Actually I got this problem in one of my blogs. I red your comment after posting this.